# Selecting lines by distance in a layer from a polyline in another layer using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, distance

I have 2 layers containing polylines.

I'd like to establish the closest distance at any point along the line of one layer to the the lines on a different layer. My assumption is that the Nearest Neighbour Analysis doesn't do this.

What is the best way?

Comment: What is the expected result ? A script, a function, datas, etc. ? For answer, for my part, I need more context.

Comment: @J.Monticolo I have a layer with a network of polylines most of which are surplus to my requirements. I only need to work with ones that are within a certain proximity to the lines on my other layer. I had hoped to created a distance field that I can use to help delete the lines not required... Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this very easy with QGIS virtual layers with a definition like this:

```
select layer1.* from layer1, layer2 where st_intersects(st_buffer(layer1.geometry, 500), layer2.geometry)
```

This will select all lines from layer1 which are in a distance from 500 (meters) to any geometry from layer2 and put the result into a new virtual layer.

[image]